# std::function::target with template parameter pack gives "error: expected primary-expression"

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

When I attempt to call the method `target` on a `std::function` object using a template parameter pack, the compiler throws an error, but it works fine if the template parameters are specified explicitly in a proxy variable.

Example, modified from [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/target):

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int f(int, int) { return 1; }
int g(int, int) { return 2; }

template <typename... Args>
void test(std::function<int(Args...)> const& arg)
{
    auto && ptr = arg.target<int(*)(Args...)>(); // error: expected primary-expression before 'int'

    if (ptr && *ptr == f)
        std::cout << "it is the function f\n";
    if (ptr && *ptr == g)
        std::cout << "it is the function g\n";
}

int test()
{
    test<int, int>(std::function<int(int, int)>(f));
    test<int, int>(std::function<int(int, int)>(g));
}
```

I've tried various other ways to call `target` including the following:

```cpp
int (*const* ptr)(Args...) = arg.target<int(*)(Args...)>(); // error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
int (*const* ptr)(int, int) = arg.target<int(*)(Args...)>(); // error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
int (*const* ptr)(int, int) = arg.target<int(*)(int, int)>(); // error: expected primary-expression before 'int'

const std::function<int(Args...)>& func = arg;
auto && ptr = arg.target<int(*)(Args...)>(); // error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
```

The compiler only appeared to be satisfied when using a proxy variable as seen here:

```cpp
const std::function<int(int, int)>& func = arg;
auto && ptr = func.target<int(*)(Args...)>(); // OK, but requires specifying the template arguments for func
```

As can be seen, this workaround deviates from the previous non-working example only by explicitly specifying the function parameters instead of relying on the parameter pack. (I could bypass the proxy variable with a static_cast e.g. `static_cast<std::function<int(int,int)>&>(arg).target<int(*)(Args...)>()`, but this also requires knowing the parameters for the cast.) If I already knew what parameters were going to be used then I wouldn't be using a variadic template since it wouldn't be necessary. But since I don't, how can I fix this? Am I doing something wrong, is this a compiler bug, or what exactly is going on here?

#### Note:

For reference, I'm compiling with GCC version 6.3.0 with MinGW on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arg.template target<int(*)(Args...)>(
```

You need to disambiguate when the std function type is dependent on template args.

C++ doesn't know `arg.target` is a template when parsing your template function prior to the function being called.  And it has to parse it before it is called; this isn't a macro.

So whenever you name a type in a context dependent on your template arguments, or instantiate a template in a context dependent on your template args, you have to tell the parser.

Comment: Thank you! I'd forgotten disambiguation was a thing. I really should learn how the compiler parses these things but they're always just convoluted enough for me to rather stick them in a black box.